# TimeConstrained Aborts not occuring when entire body of While is AbortProtected

Tags: infinite-loop, constraint

In improving my code for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560699/generalization-on-older-se-question-not-just-covering-1-but-all-rational-num/1560739#1560739) question over on Math, I seem to have run across a condition where TimeConstrained `Abort[]`s do not occur, but further computation is halted...

```
(* Cache entries are 
    {{remainder, next finger to try},{list of composites so far}}. *)
Remove[cListCache, cList];
cListCache[n_ /; And[n > 0, Element[n, Rationals]]] := {{n, 4}, {}};

(*  Attempt to express n as an Egyptian fraction with all denominators *)
(* composite.  Use no more than timeLimit seconds to start or continue *)
(* working (from cached state) on this expression.  Generate debug     *)
(* output if printDiags is True.  *)
cList[
  n_ /; And[n > 0, Element[n, Rationals]], 
  timeLimit_: 10, 
  printDiags_: False
] :=
  (* Use cached values if they are finished. *)
  If[cListCache[n][[1, 1]] === 0, 
    {0, cListCache[n][[2]]},

    Module[{
      c,  (* the accumulating list of composite denominators *)
      remainder,  (* n - Plus@@(1/c)  *)
      finger  (* run your finger through the positive composites  *)
    },
      {{remainder, finger}, c} = cListCache[n];

      cListCache[n] = TimeConstrained[

        (* Get the leading consecutive composites to build up close to n *)
        (* This should perhaps be cached and turned into a map, or some  *)
        (* other structure for quick searching. *)
        While[remainder finger > 1,
          AbortProtect[
            AppendTo[c, finger];
            remainder -= 1/finger;
            If[printDiags, Print[{finger, remainder}]];
            finger++;
            If[PrimeQ[finger], finger++]  (*  No consecutive primes above 4 *)
        ]
      ]; 

      (* Until we drive the remainder to zero, keep jumping finger to the  *)
      (* least composite large enough that its reciprocal is <= remainder. *)
      While[remainder > 0,
        AbortProtect[
          finger = Ceiling[1/remainder];
          If[PrimeQ[finger], finger++]; (*  No consecutive primes above 4 *)
          AppendTo[c, finger];
          remainder -= 1/finger;
          If[printDiags, Print[{finger, remainder}]];
        ]
      ];
      (* If we finish, cache a completed result. *)
      {{0, finger}, c}
    ,
      timeLimit,
      (* If we don't finish, cache an incomplete result. *)
      {{remainder, finger}, c}
    ]
    (* Whether finished or not, propagate the completed or incomplete *)
    (* result back out to the caller. *)
  ]
] /; And[timeLimit > 0, 
       Element[timeLimit, Reals], 
       Element[printDiags, Booleans]
     ]

N[cList[3, 10, True][[1, 1]]]
(* Much output.  On my hardware, last element of c has >166,000 digits.  *)
N[cList[3, 100, True][[1, 1]]]
(* Much output.  This completes and the last element of c has >665,000 *)
(* digits. *)
```

I'm running Mathematica 10.3.0.0 on Linux x64.

When the two `cList[3,...]` calls are enqueued to evaluate, the first never completes, even after tens of minutes, although it is TimeConstrained to give up after 10 seconds.  One CPU core is running 100% until I kill the kernel.  If the two instance of "`AbortProtect`" are changed to "`Identity`", the first call completes (in a few more than 10 seconds -- on my hardware, it seems to take noticeable time to do all the handling of the 166 kilodigit and/or 655 kilodigit last numbers in the list of composites).

The `AbortProtect[]`s are to ensure that the internal state variables are coherent (all updated together) when an `Abort[]` occurs so that cached state is coherent.

Questions:

- Is it known/expected that `AbortProtect[]`ing the entire body of a `While` will prevent reception of `Abort[]`s (from `TimeConstrained[]`)?
- What is the right mental model for how `AbortProtect[]` interacts with looping constructs?  (... if that model is different from the expectation the above code entails.)
- What is the minimal change to the above code that will ensure the bodies of the `While`s are transactions and also will be `Abort[]`able from `TimeConstrained[]`?
- Is there a less awful idiom for mixing default argument values and argument constraints?  (Delocalizing constraints to the bottom of the function body is just ... not good.)
- Other than possibly being overcautious about partial updates to the three state variables for an incomplete computation (for instance, I have not analyzed whether there is an order of updates that ensures that a subsequent continuation will produce valid output (even if it does a little redundant computation)), are there other significant improvements available?

Edit:  The parallel kernel manager also thinks these calls are going into spinloops of some sort.

```
Select[
  ParallelMap[
    {#, Length[cList[#, 3][[2]]]} &, 
    randomRational[100, {0, 6}, 10^4]],  
    (* Imagine "Rationalize[#,10^-100]& /@ RandomReal[{0,6},10^4]]", but *)
    (* with more control over the distribution of denominators.          *)
  NumberQ[#[[2]]] &];
(*  LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.3/Executables/wolfram" -subkernel -noinit -wstp,529,8]. >>  *)
(*  Kernels::rdead: Subkernel connected through KernelObject[5,local] appears dead. >>  *)
(*  Parallel`Developer`QueueRun::req: Requeueing evaluations {36} assigned to KernelObject[5,local,<defunct>].  *)
(*  LaunchKernels::clone: Kernel KernelObject[5,local,<defunct>] resurrected as KernelObject[7,local]. >>  *)
(* ... occasionally with new duplicates of the block of diagnostics above. *)
```

Comment: You might find that your needs are better met with `Internal\`WithLocalSettings`. It can be used to restore state or otherwise clean up after aborts. See [this StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586735/how-to-catch-interrupts-generated-by-timeconstrained) or [this MathGroup thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Mar/msg00427.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looking a bit more at this, I think it is the expected behavior. `TimeConstrained` in effect sets an alarm clock, and it happens to ring when deep inside a time-consuming evaluation that is itself inside the `AbortProtect`. Once it emerges from that the `Abort` generated by `TimeConstrained` can and will proceed.